# Two simple Cypher queries fail when combined

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm stumped on this one, and I think the answer will be straightforward, so let me cut right to it.

Given a graph that looks like this:

[image: Diagram of graph]

Created by a query that looks like this:

```
CREATE (simpsons:Family {name: "Simpson"})
CREATE (homer:Father {name: "Homer"})
CREATE (lisa:Daughter {name: "Lisa"})
CREATE (snowball:Pet {name: "snowball"})
CREATE (lisa)-[:owns]->(snowball)-[:has]->(:Item {name: "catnip"})
CREATE (homer)-[:has]->(:Item {name: "beer"})
CREATE (lisa)-[:has]->(:Item {name: "saxophone"})
CREATE (lisa)<-[:memberOf]-(simpsons)-[:memberOf]->(homer)
```

Why would a query that looks like this fail?

```
MATCH (f:Family),
(f)-[*1..10]-(lisa:Daughter),
(lisa)-[*1..10]-(:Item {name: "saxophone"}),
(f)-[*1..10]-(snowball:Pet),
(snowball)-[*1..10]-(:Item {name: "catnip"})
RETURN f;
```

Taken separately, its two components both find matches.

```
MATCH (f:Family),
(f)-[*1..10]-(lisa:Daughter),
(lisa)-[*1..10]-(:Item {name: "saxophone"})
RETURN f;
```

and

```
MATCH (f:Family),
(f)-[*1..10]-(snowball:Pet),
(snowball)-[*1..10]-(:Item {name: "catnip"})
RETURN f;
```

But when pieced together there are no matches.

I have tried `PROFILE`ing the query and it seems like Cypher works backwards from Snowball. It can make that first connection between the family and Snowball.

After that it does a `VarLengthExpand(All)`

```
snowball, f, lisa
(f)-[ UNNAMED22:*..10]-(lisa)
```

Which yields 6 rows. We then drop to 0 rows with this `Filter`:

```
snowball, f, lisa
lisa: Daughter
```

I can get the match to work if I declare a connection between the family and a daughter in the first line of the match statement, but for reasons having to do w/ my particular application this is not a useful workaround.

```
MATCH (f:Family)-[*1..10]-(lisa:Daughter),
(lisa)-[*1..10]-(:Item {name: "saxophone"}),
(lisa)-[*1..10]-(snowball:Pet {name: "snowball"})-[*1..10]-(:Item {name: "catnip"})
RETURN f;
```

I think I'm missing something about how Cypher searches for these patterns. Does anyone have insight into what that might be? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Cypher bug, this is a side-effect of relationship uniqueness within a given MATCH pattern.

From the [uniqueness section of the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/introduction/uniqueness/#cypherdoc-uniqueness):

> While pattern matching, Neo4j makes sure to not include matches where the same graph relationship is found multiple times in a single pattern.

This type of uniqueness is usually correct, and is great for preventing infinite loops when using variable-length relationships which traverse a cycle.

Relationship uniqueness is preserved for patterns from a MATCH or an OPTIONAL MATCH, even when these include multiple comma separated paths, as in your case.

You have all of the paths within the pattern of a single MATCH, so relationships must be unique; if used in one path, they will not be reused for another path.

The real problem is here: `(f)-[*1..10]-(snowball:Pet)` because you've already traversed the same relationship (`<memberOf` between the Simpsons and Lisa) when you did `(f)-[*1..10]-(lisa:Daughter)` earlier. Since the relationship cannot be reused, one of those two paths will not be able to be matched, so the entire MATCH fails...no such pattern exists with unique relationships.

Note that when you break up the single MATCH into multiple MATCHes, as in `stdob--`'s answer, the query succeeds. There is no uniqueness in play here between separate MATCH clauses.